# List all folders, with size but only in regexp path - LINUX

Tags: linux, directory

I have this structure

```
Folder/A 
Folder/A_SomeoneBefore/ 
Folder/B 
Folder/B_SomeoneBefore/ 
    .... 
Folder/T/TA/TAC/TAC_SomeoneAfter 
Folder/T/TA/TAF/TAF_SomeoneAfter 
Folder/T/TD/TDC/TDC_SomeoneAfter 
Folder/9/
```

I need list all folders in path Folder/[FirstLetter]/[FirstTwo]/First3/TargetFolder with size. I need ignore folder in path Folder/EveryThingWhatIsNotFirstLetter

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Just fast shoot:

```
ls -la |awk '$9 ~ "^P" {print $9}'
```

Comment: Can you send more explain of this? I tried it, but output is empty

Comment: Please send me full output of ls -la